# Get location information at regular intervals

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, location

First off, this is not a location app. The location will be sent to the service in order to check whether the user passes near certain locations. This one is for a trading application. What kind of approaches do you think there are in Flutter? How can I get location without disturbing the user in the background.

Comment: What do you mean by "in the background"? Do you mean while your app is not running (is not the foremost/only fullscreen app)?

Answer (score 0):

maybe try [Timer.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Timer/Timer.periodic.html)

```
   var _timer = Timer.periodic(
       const Duration(seconds: 300),
         (timer) {
                // your funtion
                   },
           );
```

here function will be executed every 300 seconds. and just call

```
_timer.cancel();
```

anywhere you want to stop that loop.